# How to use pid to kill process

Tags: java, android, sql, c, process

I just want to know any other ways to kill process with pid

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

try Like this.

```
 android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
 System.exit(1);
```

Comment: @Sandy You should mark the answer as "accepted" with the checkbox if you accept the solution, so the question can be marked as "solved" and so other users can find it easily.